# Different character limits in search bars

Tags: feature-request, design, character-limit, search-box

The search bar in the `.top-bar` allows a maximum of 240 characters.

```
<input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search…" value="nullpointer" 
    autocomplete="off" maxlength="240" class="f-input js-search-field">
```

[image]

---

Meanwhile the search bar in the [*Search Results*](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page allows only 140 characters max.

```
<input name="q" class="grid--cell fl1 s-input" type="text" maxlength="140"
    size="80" value="nullpointer" autocomplete="off">
```

[image]

---

Please increase the `maxlength` to 240 in the Search Results page too, as 140 is a bit less when it comes to advanced search.